# Express static middleware returning error in log

Tags: node.js, express, webpack-4

I have a completed project done on my local machine and am currently learning how to deploy it to production. I figured out a lot of things in the documentation for production and such but I have been stuck for awhile now on the part on how to tell my server to serve my static assets that contain my build files that I executed with web pack. For the record, I'm not using create-react-app I'm using the webpack-dev-server cli.

I've only ever connected to my server successfully and ran routes through it using MySQL but I never tested serving the static files on the server when my development was ready for production. I'm getting an error in the console when I try to serve my static build files. I can't tell if the error is because I have my routes being served wrong on my server or there is an issue in my index.html build.

Here is my code the server file is big so I'll only show the relevant parts pertaining to the issue I'm stuck on:

**Server file:**

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
const router = express.Router();

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(cors());
// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.get("*", function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../public/index.html"));
});

// Serve static files on server
app.use("../", express.static(__dirname + "public/index.html"));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

**Build Index.html File**

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/v4-shims.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/assets/css/pignose.calendar.min.css">
  <link href="/public/assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Ck Editor Library -->
  <script src="/public/assets/js/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <!-- Pignose Calendar -->
  <script src="/public/assets/js/pignose.calendar.full.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Webpack Production**

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

var browserConfig = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", __dirname + "/src/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          query: {
            presets: ["react", "env", "stage-0"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "sass-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CompressionPlugin({
      filename: "[path].gz[query]",
      algorithm: "gzip",
      minRatio: 0.8,
      threshold: 8192
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html"
    })
  ]
};

var serverConfig = {
  target: "node",
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: __dirname + "/server/main.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          query: {
            presets: ["react", "env", "stage-0"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = [browserConfig, serverConfig];
```

**Folder Architecture**

[image: Folder]

**Error log I'm getting when I try to connect to my port for my build files:**

[image]

second error:

[image: Second error log.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In express middleware configurations order matters, since `app.get("*", function(request, response)` is in the top every request will go through that and send the `index.html`. Change the order like this

```
// Serve static files on server

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + "/../public"));

app.get("*", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../public/index.html"));
});
```

and it should work

---

#### Edit

As your request to extend my answer, what was happening here is since you haven't configured the public direcotry, express server will get to the next request handler which is `app.get("*" , ...` which sends the `index.html` as the response. So when you request this javascript file

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

It will send the `index.html` as i mentioned without sending the `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` and same for every js and css files, but your browser is expecting a javascript file and try to parse it so the file `<!doctype> ..` is parsing and since it is not a valid javascript, it prints the error. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply back. I reorganized the order and I'm still getting the `unexpected token <` for my script files. When i go to look inside the error, it's pointing to the first line in my html file `<!doctype html>` I can send another screenshot if necessary.

Comment: Hi @Curious13 try this I edited the public serve directory as your file structure, this should work

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still getting the unexpected token error I'm submitting a screenshot of what it looks like. For the record, the server file is located in the server folder called `main.js` of my folder architecture. What I'm simply trying to do is go to `localhost:5000` and see if it will load my index.html file but it just gives me a white page with that error in that log.

Comment: You are using `/public` in your html code, this should work

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that earlier

Comment: When I start server, I'm getting no errors in the terminal it just gives me the error when I go to the browser thats why I'm confused I think I'm missing something small somewhere.

Comment: Did you try this edited code, @Curious13 use `/public` in your middleware

Comment: It works thank you :) Can you please explain what I did wrong? I apologize I'm really trying to understand what I did wrong.